# Milestones based on calendar days

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I am absolutely new to MS Project.  I need to set milestones at 25%, 50%, 75% based on days from the start of the project.  So for a 400 day project I need milestones at 100, 200, and 300.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any help. . .

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could set milestones at Start + 100 days, Start + 200 days and Start + 300 days. This could be accomplished with a predecessor on each milestone. For example, let's say your project start is a milestone at task ID 1. Then the first "progress milestone" would have a predecessor of 1FS+100d. That would set the first milestone 100 working days after project start. If you want your milestones in calendar days, the predecessor of the first progress milestone would be 1FS+100ed (elapsed days).

Bear in mind that milestone are NOT tasks, they a simply a point in time with zero duration.